# Set insets to the CollectionView programmatically in Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have `ViewController` with the `CollectionView` in it.
I want to change `CollectionView` insets by pressing button. What code I should implement?

Thank you!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Set the section inset and invalidate the layout.

```
let collectionViewLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout

collectionViewLayout?.sectionInset = ... // some UIEdgeInset

collectionViewLayout?.invalidateLayout()
```