# Add border to CollectionView

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a collection view with multiple cells in it,  I figured out how to add a border to each cell but still stuck with adding a border to the CollectionView (expected Result).

Currently, I'm placing the button outside the CollectionView but don't know how to make it looks like the expected result.

[image: Current view]

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For set the collection view border you can follow this

```
collectionView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor  
collectionView.layer.borderWidth = 5
```

And for setting cell position to the middle you need to set the cell insect. 
You can easily set the cell insect from storyboard from this. Update the `Section Insects` value that you want.

[image]

Comment: @AdorableMelon is your issue fixed?

Comment: Yes, it did fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
@IBOutlet var CollectionView: UICollectionView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

CollectionView.delegate = self
CollectionView.dataSource = self

CollectionView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor //change to required color
CollectionView.layer.borderWidth = 5 //change to required borderwidth
}
```

Comment: Big thanks! I was dumb to not think about IBOutlet, I totally forgot that.

Now i'm facing another problem that cells don't place in middle of the CollectionView  https://imgur.com/8F5O2S3. Do you know what should I do?

Comment: @AdorableMelon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975507/set-insets-to-the-collectionview-programmatically-in-swift

Comment: @AdorableMelon  select collectionview in storyboard and click on show size inspector in section insets change top,buttom,left,right to required value